# User-provided std::allocator specialization

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator

Class templates in the `::std` namespace can generally be specialized by programs for user-defined types. I did not find any exception to this rule for `std::allocator`.

So, am I allowed to specialize `std::allocator` for my own types? And if I am allowed to, do I need to provide all members of `std::allocator`'s primary template, given that many of them can be provided by `std::allocator_traits` (and are consequently deprecated in C++17)?

Consider [this program](https://godbolt.org/z/u46HCi)

```
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include<stdexcept>

struct A { };

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct allocator<A> {
        using value_type = A;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;

        allocator() = default;

        template<class U>
        allocator(const allocator<U>&) noexcept {}

        value_type* allocate(std::size_t n) {
            if(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()/sizeof(value_type) < n)
                throw std::bad_array_new_length{};
            std::cout << "Allocating for " << n << "\n";
            return static_cast<value_type*>(::operator new(n*sizeof(value_type)));
        }

        void deallocate(value_type* p, std::size_t) {
            ::operator delete(p);
        }

        template<class U, class... Args>
        void construct(U* p, Args&&... args) {
            std::cout << "Constructing one\n";
            ::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };

        template<class U>
        void destroy( U* p ) {
            p->~U();
        }

        size_type max_size() const noexcept {
            return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()/sizeof(value_type);
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    std::vector<A> v(2);
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        v.emplace_back();
    }
    std::cout << v.size();
}
```

The output of this program with libc++ (Clang with `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O2 -stdlib=libc++`) is:

```
Allocating for 2
Constructing one
Constructing one
Allocating for 4
Constructing one
Constructing one
Allocating for 8
Constructing one
Constructing one
Constructing one
Constructing one
8
```

and the output with libstdc++ (Clang with `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O2 -stdlib=libstdc++`) is:

```
Allocating for 2
Allocating for 4
Constructing one
Constructing one
Allocating for 8
Constructing one
Constructing one
Constructing one
Constructing one
8
```

As you can see libstdc++ does not always honor the overload of `construct` that I have provided and if I remove the `construct`, `destroy` or `max_size` members, then the program doesn't even compile with libstdc++ complaining about these missing members, although they are supplied by `std::allocator_traits`.

Does the program have undefined behavior and are therefore both standard libraries correct, or is the program's behavior well-defined and the standard library required to use my specialization?

---

Note that there are some members from `std::allocator`'s primary template that I still left out in my specialization. Do I need to add them as well?

To be precise, I left out

```
using is_always_equal = std::true_type
```

which is provided by `std::allocator_traits` since my allocator is empty, but would be part of `std::allocator`'s interface.

I also left out `pointer`, `const_pointer`, `reference`, `const_reference`, `rebind` and `address`, all of which are provided by `std::allocator_traits` and deprecated in C++17 for `std::allocator`'s interface.

If you think that it is required to define all of these to match `std::allocator`'s interface, then please consider them added to the code.

Comment: I take this all back. I tried it in Visual Studio 2019 and it has all the constructor calls (even the copy constructor calls). . Nevertheless, I guess libstdc++ implements it in a way that the optimizer thinks it can remove them.

Answer (score 3):

According to 23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]/3:

> For the components affected by this subclause that declare an `allocator_type`, objects stored in these components shall be constructed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct` function

Also, according to 17.6.4.2.1:

> The program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

I don't think the standard prohibits specializing `std::allocator`, since I read through all sections on `std::allocator` and it didn't mention anything. I also looked at what it looks like for the standard to prohibit specialization and I didn't find anything like it for `std::allocator`.

The requirements for `Allocator` are [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator), and your specialization satisfies them.

Therefore, I can only conclude that libstdc++ actually violates the standard (perhaps I made a mistake somewhere). I found that if one simply specializes `std::allocator`, libstdc++ will respond by using placement new for the constructor because they have a template specialization specifically for this case while using the specified allocator for other operations; the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/aeb430aadc3c91af50095be924365981d85f8b8a/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h#L658) (this is in `namespace std`; `allocator` here is `::std::allocator`):

```cpp
  // __uninitialized_default_n_a
  // Fills [first, first + n) with n default constructed value_types(s),
  // constructed with the allocator alloc.
  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Size, typename _Allocator>
    _ForwardIterator
    __uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator __first, _Size __n, 
                _Allocator& __alloc)
    {
      _ForwardIterator __cur = __first;
      __try
    {
      typedef __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Allocator> __traits;
      for (; __n > 0; --__n, (void) ++__cur)
        __traits::construct(__alloc, std::__addressof(*__cur));
      return __cur;
    }
      __catch(...)
    {
      std::_Destroy(__first, __cur, __alloc);
      __throw_exception_again;
    }
    }

  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Size, typename _Tp>
    inline _ForwardIterator
    __uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator __first, _Size __n, 
                allocator<_Tp>&)
    { return std::__uninitialized_default_n(__first, __n); }
```

`std::__uninitialized_default_n` calls `std::_Construct` which uses placement new. This explains why you don't see "Constructing one" before "Allocating for 4" in your output.

**EDIT:**
As OP pointed out in a comment, [`std::__uninitialized_default_n`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/aeb430aadc3c91af50095be924365981d85f8b8a/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h#L610) calls

```cpp
__uninitialized_default_n_1<__is_trivial(_ValueType)
                             && __assignable>::
__uninit_default_n(__first, __n)
```

which actually has a specialization if `__is_trivial(_ValueType) && __assignable` is `true`, which is [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/aeb430aadc3c91af50095be924365981d85f8b8a/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h#L578). It uses `std::fill_n` (where `value` is trivially constructed) instead of calling `std::_Construct` on each element. Since `A` is trivial and copy assignable, it would actually end up calling this specialization. Of course, this does not use `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct` either.

Comment: In my specific case it is not actually using the `std::_Construct` call from what I can tell, because `A` is trivially copyable and trivially copy assignable, therefore the the other specialization of `__uninitialized_default_n_1` is chosen, which calls `std::fill_n` instead, which then again dispatches to `memcpy`/`memset`. I was aware of this as an optimization libstdc++ makes, but I didn't realize that the `std::allocator::construct` call is also skipped for non-trivial types. So it may just be an oversight in how libstdc++ identifies that the library-supplied `std::allocator` is used.